# React and Typescript Interface "OR" operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

I am starting to develop an application with React and Typescript. I am newbie with the 2 things by the way.

I have a react component and some interface, I want the every field in that interface is required, but if one specific field is implemented the others are not required anymore.

In this case if I set "object" I would like to not need implement the other 2 fields.

```
interface ITextFieldProps {
    label: string,
    required: boolean,
    object?: any
}

export default class TextField extends React.Component<ITextFieldProps, any> {
    ...
}
```

Hope someone can help, cheers!

**EDIT**

First of all I want to thank all the answers, I really learned a lot with each one of them. They helped me to understand my problem and to find the best solution.

The object that I will pass is a metadata so it will be only available in runtime after a http call. That being said, I cannot check and type it at dev time anyway.

So I solved my problem using the react props spread.

(Today it is not supported by typescript, but someday it will be someday hehe https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103):

```
export interface IMetadata {
    label: string,
    required: boolean
}

interface TextFieldProps extends IMetadata {
    ...
}
```

This way i can pass one object with the props spread and then when i call the label="" it will overwrite the label comming in {...this.metadata.nome} automatically:

```
<TextField {...this.metadata.nome} label="OverwriteLabel" />
```

**EDIT 2**

And as Daniel said:
Unfortunately the type checking in JSX has a bug, see:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10171

They plan to fix it for 2.1. Until then, this technique won't work for TSX. (When it is fixed, I will come back and update this answer.)

Comment: Is the structure of the object completely unknown? If so, how do you get `label` and `required` in that case? My recommendation would be to make the interface fixed and map the object to the correct props where necessary. In my opinion, having "clever" components that might do one thing or another depending on what you throw at them just makes things more complicated.

Comment: Actually the object is known, it will be a json with all those properties (label, required and many others) the best scene is pass the object so the developer dont need to write too much, but if he don't have that object and need to use the component, the component will require those X props in the interface... @TomFenech

Answer (score 9):

This is done in TypeScript with a union type.

```
interface TextFieldPropsA {
    label: string,
    required: boolean
}

interface TextFieldPropsB {
    object: any
}
```

Here's how you can define a union of those:

```
type TextFieldProps = TextFieldPropsA | TextFieldPropsB;
```

This literally means it must be the first or the second type (it's exactly what you asked for in your question! We're "or"-ing two interfaces).

So:

```
// no good
const test1: TextFieldProps = { }

// no good, still missing the label
const test2: TextFieldProps = {
    required: true
} 

// this is fine
const test1: TextFieldProps = {
    object: {}
}
```

(By the way, note that the `I` prefix is not widely used in TypeScript, because classes and function types are all interfaces so it really doesn't tell you anything useful.)

**UPDATE** However, you require this to define React props, so you can restrict what is allowed when using JSX syntax. Unfortunately the type checking in JSX has a bug, see:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10171

They plan to fix it for 2.1. Until then, this technique won't work for TSX. (When it's fixed I'll come back and update this answer!)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, there's no way to express in an interface that if one property is satisfied then the other aren't needed.

You have two options (as I see it):

(1) Declare all properties as optional:

```
interface ITextFieldProps {
    label?: string,
    required?: boolean,
    object?: any
}
```

And then check if the value is valid:

```
function isValid(props: ITextFieldProps): boolean {
    return props.label || props.required != null || props.object;
}
```

(2) Define a few interfaces which extend a base one:

```
interface ITextFieldPropsBase {}

interface ITextFieldPropsLabel extends ITextFieldPropsBase {
    label: string;
}

interface ITextFieldPropsBool extends ITextFieldPropsBase {
    value: boolean;
}

interface ITextFieldPropsAny extends ITextFieldPropsBase {
    object: any;
}

class TextField<T extends ITextFieldPropsBase> extends React.Component<T, any> { ... }
```

This way you only get one of those properties each time.

---

#### Edit

@DanielEarwicker commented about how do props are being passed into the component in my 2nd example.
When using `jsx`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<TextField label="hey" />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

It errors that `label` cannot be found, but it can be done using `ReactDOM.render`:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(TextField, { label: "hey" }), document.getElementById("container"));
```

---

#### 2nd Edit

It seems that my 2nd suggestion isn't a good one for this specific case.
I derived it from a slightly different scenario that I have:

```
interface BaseProps {
    name: string;
}

abstract class BaseComponent<T extends BaseProps> extends React.Component<T, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div className={ this.props.name }>{ this.getContent() }</div>
    }

    protected abstract getContent(): JSX.Element;
}

interface DateProps extends BaseProps {
    date: Date;
}

class DateComponent extends BaseComponent<DateProps> {
    protected getContent(): JSX.Element {
        return <div>{ DateComponent.formatDate(this.props.date) }</div>
    }

    private static formatDate(date: Date): string {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As I actually have a different component class for each of the interfaces then I have no need to do any type guards, casting or any other tricks.

The answer by @DanielEarwicker is the right one in the scenario described by the OP.

Comment: This is perfectly possible, via union types - see my answer.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker That's also an option, but it's not that different than my 2nd option, and using type guards isn't that comfortable (in my opinion) in certain scenarios such as the props in react.

Comment: What did you mean by your first sentence? :) And how does the component get the values of the properties with your approach?

Comment: I meant that the 2nd option in my answer isn't very different than your solution, as it is kinda like `ITextFieldPropsLabel | ITextFieldPropsBool | ITextFieldPropsAny`. And you're right, it's not easy to pass the props using `jsx`, it can be done using `React.createElement`. But the same goes to you, how do you pass the props in `jsx` with your solution?

Comment: I've just found that there is a bug in the TSX support, so my approach won't work either. But from 2.1 onward it should be correct :) Note that your 2nd approach is not the same. `T extends ITextFieldPropsBase` is satisfied by things that don't fit the requirement, such as the empty object `{}` which has no properties. Whereas my answer only allows what the OP requires (`object` on its own, or *both* the other two properties). My question was more about inside the component, when it wants to read the values of `this.props`. How can that be done safely without type guards?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker Other than the empty object what else satisfies it to make it different? As for reading the props, you're right here as well, after playing with it I realized that applying this way in this scenario isn't as good as I thought. I took it from a similar problem I have, but I'm handling things differently (see my 2nd edit). In the case of the OP's question your answer makes more sense, you've got my vote.

Comment: Thanks! Try https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20f%3CT%20extends%20%7B%7D%3E(o%3A%20T)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Af(%7B%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Af(5)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Af(true)%3B - by saying that a type extends the empty object, you are not really constraining it at all. You can pass a number, a Boolean, any object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the minimal interface for this component is always:

```
interface ITextFieldProps {
    label: string;
    required: boolean;
}
```

But sometimes you have an object with more properties than just those two.

If that's the case, then you can just pass the more complex object as props to the component. As long as it has those two properties defined, it's OK.

---

In response to your comments, I'd warn against making the props too flexible - it comes at the cost of making the component unnecessarily complex. I'd suggest always passing named individual props rather than using a more general `object` prop.

I guess that you can use something like this:

```
// use the object
const { label, required } = object;

// ...or use a mixture
const { label } = object;
const required = false;

// ...or define everything manually
const label = "label";
const required = true;

return <TextField label={label} required={required} />;
```

This way, the last line remains the same in all cases, so the props interface doesn't need to do anything fancy.

Comment: Actually the object is known, a json metadata serverside with all those properties (label, required...) so the developer team dont need to write all props one by one, just pass the obj and the component mount itself. But if he wants to write all component props without the json and with intelissense? I dont know if i'm being clear, but it seems to not be possible, and i'll have to do as Nitzan 1) option.

Comment: So you're saying that if the more complex object is available, then you'd like to use those properties within the component too?

Comment: In theory the object will have everything that make the component work.
But if the front-end developer want to change something he can call something like `<MyComponent object={MyObject} label={MyNewLabel} />`.
In other situation if he don't want to use the object and write down all required props like `<MyComponent label="Label" required="false" />`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the approach that I would recommend using.